join_load in SQLAlchemy 2.0.27
I have problems with load_only method in SQLAlchemy
Here are my database models
class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, autoincrement=False, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))
    # ... other fields

    private_courses: Mapped[List["PrivateCourse"]] = relationship(
        "PrivateCourse", back_populates="student", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

class PrivateCourse(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    student_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))
    # ... other fields

    student: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="private_courses", lazy='raise')

But my code returns all fields for Student
def get_private_course_by_course_id(db: Session, private_course_id: int) -> PrivateCourse | None:
    query = (
        db.query(PrivateCourse)
        .options(subqueryload(PrivateCourse.student).load_only(User.id))
        .filter(private_course_id == PrivateCourse.id)
    )

    return query.first()

I tried use all of these methods defaultload, selectinload, contains_eager, subqueryload but nothing helps.
I want to load PrivateCourse ONLY with id and first_name for Student

"But my code returns all fields for Student" - How are you determining that? Note that if you run course = get_private_course_by_course_id(sess, 1) and then try to access one of the other attributes, e.g., print(course.student.date_of_birth) SQLA will automatically lazy-load that value by issuing another SELECT query.
